# How to setup a cs:go offline server on which friends can join

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

When I start an offline match and invite my mate he gets an connection error "Server does not respond".

How may I set up a "Offline with Bots" - Server on which my friend can join?

**EDIT :**
I meant an offline server within a local area network.

Comment: "Offline with Bots" = no connections allowed.  I don't know CS, but it sounds like you need an option that says something like, "Online with/without Bots".

Comment: Yeah right but this option does not exist -.- I wouldn´t post this question if it were that easy :3

Answer (score 4):

You can connect with friends with bots added in all modes except classic competitive simply by going to play with friends and sending them an invite.  You can do the same in classic competitive by setting up play with bots game and having your friends connect to your ip address thru the developer console (connect xxx.xx.xxx.xx). You need to port forward to 27015 doing it that way.

Answer (score 2):

An offline server is exactly what the title implies, an offline server where no one from the outside can join under normal settings.

You can find empty servers with bots in them by using the Community Servers option and searching for servers that way and then inviting your friend to that empty server with bots in it.

If you are on the same internal network as a friend: An "offline with bots" game still creates a local server on port 27015. Get your internal IP and your friend should be able to connect to it. Depending on your firewall settings of course.

Comment: Offline server is not implying that nobody from the outside can join. Offline only implies, that there is no connection to the internet. A Local game server is also an offline server, even if you are able to connect another player with a network cable in the Local Are Network.

Comment: Well if your friends are part of the same network that would put them "inside" your network wouldn't it? It was implied that people on the Internet cannot connect to the offline server. Anything outside of your local infrastructure cannot connect.

Comment: Yes, but in this case my friend was in my local area network.

Comment: A local area network, where nobody has access to the internet but we still have a connection to each other using a network switch

Comment: In that case you need to get your IP address and have your friend connect to your server that way. An "offline with bots" game still creates a local server on port 27015. Get your internal IP and your friend should be able to connect to it. Depending on your firewall settings of course.

Comment: This is the answer I was hoping for when I asked.

Comment: "An offline server is exactly what the title implies, an offline server where no one from the outside can join." That's actually false, I've just played with a mate on my "Offline with bots" server, and we are NOT in the same local network. I've just forwarded port 27015 to my PC on the router, just like @lpack suggested.

Comment: If you want to go with the technical route then absolutely this is possible. But by opening your port and computer up to the internet you are no longer technically "offline". You've made your computer an "online" server. In this example you are playing in the "offline with bots" *mode* while being online.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an offline server with your friend by creating a private lobby and calling all the friends that you want. Then u can choose going casual or workshop maps. In this case, nobody can log into "your server"! =D

Comment: This works, You go to Main Menu, play game and then play with friends, invite them all and click play, steam will take care of rest.

Answer (score 1):

Playing offline with bots is exactly what it says on the tin; you're offline, with outside connections being accepted.

To play with your friends, you'll need to set up a **private server.** Doing this is actually pretty easy, but you will need to know how to forward ports on your router, and you will need to download the CS:GO server files.

If you can't access the admin page on your router, or your router doesn't support specific port forwarding, or if you simply don't want to download a bunch of files, the easier route is to **find an empty server.** That's right, the simplest way to play with friends is find an empty server through the Community server list, and invite them there. This eliminates any of the hassle of setup, but you may get random players.

If you can get into your router and you can forward ports, here's what you need to do:

- You will need to download and install [SteamCMD.](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD#Downloading_SteamCMD) That link has some more detailed instructions, but basically just make a folder named "steamcmd" somewhere, download the file in the link, and extract it to your new folder.
- Once you have SteamCMD, you'll need to download the server files for CSGO. This is basically redownloading the entire game, with some added features for servers. Open SteamCMD, and type the following commands:

  > force_install_dir c:\csgo-ds\
  >   force_install_dir .\csgo-ds\

This will create a directory for you to install the files to, and it will then open that directory in SteamCMD.

- Once you have the path set, download the files with this command:

  > app_update 740 validate

Once this finishes, you now have the required files for the game. The next step is to forward your ports.

- To forward a port on your router, you'll need to know the make and model of your router. Once you know this, go to [this website.](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/routerindex.htm) It has specific guides for many routers, and will give you a much more detailed guide on the specific process. The basic process, is to log into the router, look for the port section. This will include a number of boxes, and drop down boxes with letters like TCP. Some routers have this area specifically labelled.
- Once you have found the port forwarding section on your router's control panel, you will need to put in CS:GO's ports. CS:GO uses UDP **and** TCP, so make sure it is set to use both. Then forward the ports as follows:

  > start 27015
  >   end 27015

These are the standard ports used by CS:GO, however your server may start on a different port for whatever reason. If those ports don't work, move the start and the end up by one for each try; for example, if that didn't work, the next step would be 27016.

**Remember to close your ports after shutting down your server.**
It can be a security issue to keep ports open and unused. This can open you up to attacks, so make sure you close the router when you're done hosting the server.

- Finally, once you have sucessfully downloaded all the files and sucessfully forwarded your ports, use one of the following commands to start your server:

  > **Casual:** srcds -game csgo -console -usercon +game_type 0 +game_mode 0 +mapgroup mg_active +map de_dust2
  >   **Competitive:** srcds -game csgo -console -usercon +game_type 0 +game_mode 1 +mapgroup mg_active +map de_dust2
  >   **Arms Race:** srcds -game csgo -console -usercon +game_type 1 +game_mode 0 +mapgroup mg_armsrace +map ar_shoots
  >   **Deathmatch:** srcds -game csgo -console -usercon +game_type 1 +game_mode 2 +mapgroup mg_allclassic +map de_dust
- So now your server is running, and your ports are forwarded. Once the server has been started, it should give you an IP to tell you where your server is running; if not, Google "what is my IP?" and that will tell you. Copy that number, and put :27015 on the end (or whatever port you ended up forwarding.) The number will look like this; 192.168.0.1:27015.
  To connect to your server, take this full number you now have, open your console in CSGO (the console is opened with the ~ key), and type "connect (your IP/port.)" So again for example, I would put "connect 192.168.0.1:27015" without the quotation marks, into my console.

That covers the basics of it. The initial link I provided will go into details of adjusting specific server configurations, such as grenades that are allowed, disabling certain weapons, setting up a map rotation, etc. It is a little bit complicated and a little bit daunting the first time you do it. But forwarding a port is the most difficult part, and once you learn how to do that on your router, it should be pretty easy from there on.

Comment: My issue is that when someone is playing on my server I see them in game "Playing on community server" but there is now option to join them.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create a offline server then type "status " in the console and you will get a IP address, give that IP address to your friend and type"connect-the IP address" and then you are good to go

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible.  When you create a server from the main menu, you must input the `sv_lan 0` command into the console.  Then type in `status` to see the IP number. then others can connect using the command `connect (IP number)`. Also you can remove bots using 'bot quota'. You must also have Hamachi.  After it's done, your friend can join.