# Turn off steam logon requirment for LAN CSGO

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive, source-engine

I have a LAN game of CSGO set up using the sv_lan method. This works fine, but where we like to play has an unreliable internet connection, and we often want to play when there if no internet availible. This means we are instantly kicked, saying "No steam login".

Is there a way I can override the need for a Steam login when I'm playng in a local server?

All the players do have legit versions of CSGO on their Steam accounts, it's just the server can't verify them.

Comment: possible answer here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87401/how-to-setup-a-csgo-offline-server-on-which-friends-can-join

Answer (score 1):

It happens when you have an internet connection in your background,
The best solution is to turn off your internet connection and run steam in offline mode,it wont show no steam login...
and if you are playing offline,you can override your steam login,
disconnect your internet connection and when login screen appears...enter any username which is already used on that pc then you can enter any password 
**NOTE** it will only work if you have disconnected your internet connection